# SwiftUI: Using CGAffineTransform to scale a Path to fit a View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a drawing I am generating from a array of array of CGPoints (i.e. [[CGPoints]]) in its own struct (the struct itself has some extra data)...I am trying to display the line in my view using the following code:

```
class Drawing: ObservableObject {

@Published private var lines = [Line]()
@Published var currentIndex = 0

public var visibleLines: [Line] {
        Array(lines.prefix(currentIndex))
    }

}

class Line: ObservableObject {

    var lineIndex = 0
    var points = [CGPoint]()
}


Struct View: View {

@Published var drawing = Drawing()


 func add(line: Line, to path: inout Path) {
            let points = line.points

            guard points.count > 1 else {
                return
            }

            for i in 0 ..< points.count - 1 {
                let current = points[i]
                let next = points[i + 1]
                path.move(to: current)
                path.addLine(to: next)
            }
            
            
        }

var body: some View {

GeometryReader { geometry in

 let frame = CGRect(x: geometry.frame(in: .local).minX, y: geometry.frame(in: .local).minY, width: geometry.frame(in: .local).width, height: geometry.frame(in: .local).height)

Path { path in
     for line in drawing.visibleLines {
      add(line: line, to: &path)
        }
     } 
     .scaled(for: frame)
     .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
     .frame(alignment: .center) 
   }

 }
}

extension Path {
    func scaled(for rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        
        let scaleX = boundingRect.width/rect.width
        print("scaleX = \(scaleX)")
        let scaleY = boundingRect.height/rect.height
        print("scaleY = \(scaleY)")
        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)
        print("scale = \(scale)")
        return applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
        
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the drawing to be as large as possible in the middle of the view, but currently it is small and scales up as the user adds points to the drawing. I thought the CGAffineTransform would scale the points to fit per the view (via the GeometryReader frame I am creating), but it seems to do the opposite. I also tried (in my "scaled" modifier) switching the math to rect.width/boundingRect.width and rect.height/boundingRect.height, but the line wasn't visible in the view...